# Cannot find symbol when calculating whether weekend

Tags: java, calendar

I am trying to check whether a given day is a weekend or not, but I am receiving an error saying

```
if (startDate.get(DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SATURDAY && (startDate.get(DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY))
```

With the pointer under `SUNDAY`

Not too sure what the issue here is, as I am sure I have imported all the relevant classes necessary, as well as the fact that `startDate` is in `Calendar` format. Anyone know what the issue here is?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.lang.*;

//some code...

if (startDate.get(DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SATURDAY && (startDate.get(DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't imported the constants in a `static` way, you have to access them via their class name like

```
if (startDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)  ...
                  ^^^^^^^^^
```

everywhere where you use those static fields.

Answer (score 1):

The `DAY_OF_WEEK` constant is part of the `Calendar` class.  Use:

```
if (startDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SATURDAY && 
    startDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY)
```

I.e. `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK`, not `DAY_OF_WEEK`.

Or you could use a static import:

```
import static java.util.Calendar.*;
```

Answer (score 1):

`DAY_OF_WEEK` is an constant in [**java.util.Calendar**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_WEEK) class.

```
public static final int DAY_OF_WEEK
```

> Field number for get and set indicating the day of the week. This
>   field takes values SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY,
>   FRIDAY, and SATURDAY.

```
if (startDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SATURDAY && (startDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY)) {
```